# Give an example of contraction function that has no fixed points.

Tags: contraction-operator

So we have a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is a contraction mapping. Can we find any example of $f$ that has no fixed points? We take into account standard Euclidean distance.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

We have the [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem#Statement), which says you cannot.

The intuition: if you are in a metric space which is *complete* (meaning all Cauchy sequences have a limit), then a contraction applied to an arbitrary starting point will define a Cauchy sequence through its iterations, which in turn defines a limit. With some work, you can show that the limit of this sequence is a fixed point of the function. With a bit more work, you show that actually *any* such sequence gives you the same fixed point, regardless of the starting point, so you even get uniqueness!

**Good point from the comments**: In this context, a contraction is understood as a function $f$ such that
$$ d(f(x), f(y)) \leq c d(x, y),$$
uniformly, for some constant $c <1$. Having
$$ d(f(x), f(y)) <  d(x, y),$$
is not sufficient, as one can concoct counterexamples!

Comment: And notice how important that $|f(x)-f(y)|/|x-y|$ is not just less than $1$ but universally bounded by a constant less than $1$: otherwise $f(x) = x - \arctan x - \frac\pi2$ would be a counterexample.

Comment: Okay, on the other hand. We know that definition of contraction is that there exists $\alpha \in (0,1)$ that for all $x$ and $y$ we have $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq \alpha |x-y|$ if it comes to metric space that I talked about before. I am wondering, if we could swap quantifiers and find function $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$\forall_{x,y\in\mathbb{R}} \exists_{\alpha\in(0,1)} |f(x)-f(y)|\leq \alpha |x-y|$$
and has no fixed points.

Comment: Norbert, what you describe is relaxing the uniformity requirement. Greg's comment gives an example of such function.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I am trying to show that $f(x)$ holds requirments that I talked and I stucked:
$$|x-y+\arctan(y)-\arctan(x)| \leq |x-y| + |\arctan(y)-\arctan(x)|$$ What's next?

Comment: Don't do it directly; compute the derivative of $f$ and use the mean value theorem.

Comment: I know this theorem, but I am not sure how to use it

Comment: The mean value theorem gives you, for every pair $x, y$, $x < y$,
$$\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} = f'(c)$$
for some $c \in [x, y]$. Call the left hand side $L$, you want to show $|L| < 1$ holds but $|L| \leq c < 1$ does not hold for any $c\in(0, 1)$. You can prove this for the right hand side, $f'(c)$, instead, by proving it for $f'$ at every point.

Comment: Ohhh yes! Thank you very much! Now I see it.